# .NET assembly in bin folder isn't found by webservice

Tags: .net, asp.net, dll

I'm trying to deploy a webservice, and everything worked fine, until I changed the version number of one of the referenced dll's.

The old version used to be 1.0.0.0 the new one is 1.0.0.1. This assembly is in the GAC (the SharePoint application also uses it) and in de bin folder of the webservice.

I have re-compiled the application multiple times (debug and release). I recycled the application pool, I restarted the webserver from IIS manager. I have deleted the temporary files in C:\windows\Microsoft.Net... Nothing helped.

I build in Visual Studio 2008, and then I publish from within Visual Studio. The references in VS all look right (version numbers of assemblies).

Even if I use reflector, it tells me that the dll refers to the 1.0.0.1 version of the assembly. But the service keep throwing an exception about not being able to load assembly with version number 1.0.0.0.

The only quick fix I can figure out is to change the version number to 1.0.0.0. But then I'm not even sure what version of the code really is loaded...

By the way I'm running on Windows Server 2008 and using Framework 3.5.

Comment: I mean whether its getting updated in web.config ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [Assembly Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28VS.71%29.aspx) in the web.config. You could also try removing and re-adding the reference in VS, this helps sometimes, also do a clean build.